# Como alterar o tamanho, cor e adicionar bold nas pastas e no nome das mesmas no VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Seguinte, utilizo o Vs code para desenvolvimento, mesmo instalando temas diferentes, ainda não consegui achar um plugin que altere o tamanho e cor das pastas da sidebar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Percebam, que as pastas do lado esquerdo, são de tamanho muito pequeno e seus nomes são muito apagados, onde posso alterar essas configurações?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não faz isso através de tema, e sim aplicando suas configurações personalizadas.

Conforme descrito na [documentação](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings)

Como exemplo, essa configuração vai mudar a cor dos nomes de pastas.

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  "sideBar.foreground": "#fff"
}
```

Particularmente acho estranho, mas você pode por exemplo usar `"window.zoomLevel": -0.5`  vai dar um zoom em todo `vscode` (incluindo a barra lateral) e, em seguida, para compensar você pode definir `"editor.fontSize"` para o seu gosto.

Answer (score 3):

Uma "gambiarra" seria dar uns `Ctrl++`, isso vai fazer com que todas as fontes fiquem bem maiores.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Depois vc via nos Settings e muda o tamanho da fonte só do editor de texto para um tamanho que achar interessante.**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Exemplo exagerado**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]